# Wrong model stub when testing controllers which using inherited_resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec2, inherited-resources

I'm new to RSpec and my controllers're using inherited_resources, I have this mock/stub setup like:

```
describe MarketsController do
  def mock_market(stubs={})
    @mock_market ||= mock_model(Market, stubs).as_null_object
  end

  describe "GET index" do
    it "assigns all markets as @markets" do
      Market.stub(:all){ [mock_market] }
      get :index

      assigns(:markets).should eql([mock_market])
    end
  end
end
```

And this spec fails because there's nothing in the assigns(:markets). After I added:

```
class MarketsController
    def index
        @markets = Market.all
    end
end
```

it'll pass so I guess that's because the inherited_resources doesn't call **Market.all** to get all of the Market instance and thus bypass the stub for **Market.stub(:all)**. The **index** method I added above is obviously redundant and shouldn't exist at all, so the question is, without call Market.all explicitly, what should I do in my spec to complete the tests? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am reading the code correctly, `inherited_resources` first tries to use `Market.scoped` if it exists. So do you have a `scoped` scope?

Comment: Yes, this solved my problem! I didn't know that it's using Resource.scoped to get all the resources before, Thanks!